# Discrepency in the monad bind and unit function?

Tags: haskell, monads

### Problem

I am just going through the [You Could Have Invented Monads!](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) tutorial, and in the section entitled **A Container: Multivalued Functions**, where the function types (of complex square and cube roots) are:

```
Complex Float -> [Complex Float]
```

Bind is defined as:

```
bind :: (Complex Double -> [Complex Double]) -> ([Complex Double] -> [Complex Double])
bind f x = concat (map f x)
--shortcut:
f * g = bind f . g
```

and unit and lift are:

```
unit x = [x]    
lift f = unit . f
```

Now I am confused, is the `f` in `lift` function the same as the `f` in the `bind` function?
In other words what are the type of the `unit` and `lift` functions?

### Paradox

Also, by my reasoning I come to a strange paradox: If `lift` can take functions such as:

```
realRoot :: Double -> Double
realRoot x =  sqrt(x)
```

and lift it into our monad so that it becomes of type:

```
lift realRoot :: [Complex Double]
```

wouldn't I be able to do stuff like:

```
(lift realRoot * imaginaryRoot) -1
```

where

```
imaginaryRoot :: [Complex Double]
```

But how can I take *real* root of *complex* numbers?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I am confused, is the `f` in `lift` function the same as the `f` in the bind function? In other words what are the type of the `unit` and `lift` functions?

No, it's not the same. `lift`'s argument is a function `Complex Double -> Complex Double`, so

```
unit :: Complex Double -> [Complex Double]
lift :: (Complex Double -> Complex Double) -> (Complex Double -> [Complex Double])
```

and thus your `realRoot` is not an acceptable argument for `lift`.